# How to decompress WoW data

Tags: c++, compression, zlib, inflate, world-of-warcraft

I have pcap file with World of Warcraft traffic and I need to uncompress it. I know that it is compressed by Zlib:
http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/List_Of_Compressed_Games
So to find the beginning of a compressed block i wrote a piece of code that iterates through raw data,tries to decompress data and checks whether some output available.

I call inflateInit2 function to initialize zlib with windowBits parameters 15(zlib format) and 30(gzip format). I tried inflate() with Z_SYNC_FLUSH and Z_FULL_FLUSH parameter.
But it gives me no output.

[Ip traffic looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5i3l.png)

Each packet ends with 00 00 00 ff ff. But zlib manual says that it has to be 00 00 ff ff.

*So what is the way to extract data from WoW stream?*

My code is:

```
void tryZlib(unsigned __int8 *StPt, __int64 size, Deflate *zlib)
{
    z_stream_s *  stream = new z_stream_s;
    SecureZeroMemory(stream, sizeof(z_stream_s));
    bool isInit = false;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        BYTE *out_buf;
        bool isPacketLost = false;
        unsigned __int32 total_out = 0;
        Zlib::ZlibData ddata(StPt, size, *stream, isInit, isPacketLost);
        auto IsOk = zlib->Decoder(ddata, out_buf, total_out);
        zlib->Reset(*stream, isInit);
        --size;
        ++StPt;
    }
}
```

Inflate wrapper function:

```
bool Zlib::Decoder(const DeflateData & ddata, BYTE *& out_data, unsigned __int32 & size)
    {
        if (IsDllLoaded == false || ddata.PDU == nullptr || ddata.PDU_size == 0)
            return false;
        z_stream_s & strm = ddata.stream;
        if (!ddata.isInitialized)
            Init(ddata);
        strm.total_out = 0;
        strm.avail_in = ddata.PDU_size;
        strm.next_in = ddata.PDU;
        strm.avail_out = OUT_BUFFER_SIZE;
        strm.next_out = out_buffer;
        __int32 ret = 0;
        bool isWasSync = false;
        ret = ZDecompressor(&strm,  Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        size = strm.total_out;
        if ((ret = 0) || (size > 10))
            printf("Found!!"); 
        out_data = out_buffer;
        return true;            
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about WoW, but if a packet ends with `00 00 00 ff ff` doesn't that imply that it ends with `00 00 ff ff`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in other streams I saw only 00 00 ff ff wihtout 00 before it. That it why I say so..

Comment: It's possible the extra `00` is part of the payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `windowBits` parameter to be `-15` (negative) in order to request raw deflate.

The stored block you are referring to is three zero *bits*, followed by filling the rest of that byte with enough zero bits to get to a byte boundary, followed by the four bytes `00 00 ff ff`. So depending on the preceding bits in the stream, the byte before the `00 00 ff ff` may not be `00`.

Comment: It helped me! Thanks